# Dynamic Marker on geocoding from PHP MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the values of the coordinates from my database and place a marker on all the saved positions. I shows no errors but it is not placing the markers on the map. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<div id="floating-panel">
  <input id="address" type="textbox" placeholder="type your address here">
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Click for location">
</div>
```

```
<script>
  function initMap() {
      var mapProp = {
         center: {lat: 33.641656100000000000, lng: 72.983588599999960000},
          zoom:8,
          panControl:true,
          zoomControl:true,
          mapTypeControl:true,
          scaleControl:true,
          streetViewControl:true,
          overviewMapControl:true,
          rotateControl:true,    
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };



var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapProp);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
      geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
    });
  }




  function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lat());
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: resultsMap,
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
          animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        });
        //var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        //var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        window.location = "distance_cal.php?Latitude=" +  results[0].geometry.location.lat() + "&Longitude="+ results[0].geometry.location.lng();

      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }

    });




        <?php
        $query = mysql_query("select * from saved_positions") or die (mysql_error());
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        { 
            $scl=$row['school_name'];
            $city=$row['city'];
            $lon2=urlencode($row['longitude_s']);
            $lat2=urlencode($row['latitude_s']);
    ?>
        var lat='<?php echo '$lat2'?>';
        var lon='<?php echo '$lon2'?>';
        var myLatLng = {lat, lng};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: ResultMap,
          position: myLatLng,
          animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        });
    <?php
        }
    ?>

  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is very strange code.

```
var lat='<?php echo '$lat2'?>';
var lon='<?php echo '$lon2'?>';
var myLatLng = {lat, lng};
```

This should be like this:

```
var lat = <?php echo $lat2?>;
var lon = <?php echo $lon2?>;
var myLatLng = {lat: lat, lng: lon};
```

And where did you define the variable `ResultMap` in your code?

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: ResultMap,  // <--- where does this value come from?
      position: myLatLng,
      animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
});
```

I recommend you use any template system (such as smart, or something) to separate PHP code and JS code.

Comment: `ResultMap` is defined inside the call to `geocodeAddress`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have typos in your code:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: lng is not defined
```

This is not the correct way to define a [google.maps.LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngLiteral):

```
  var lat='<?php echo '$lat2'?>';
  var lon='<?php echo '$lon2'?>';
  var myLatLng = {lat, lng};
```

Should be:

```
  var lat='<?php echo '$lat2'?>';
  var lon='<?php echo '$lon2'?>';
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: lat,
    lng: lon
  };
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/48h7u4v6/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: {
      lat: 33.6416561,
      lng: 72.9835886
    },
    zoom: 8,
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
    overviewMapControl: true,
    rotateControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapProp);
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
  });

  function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: resultsMap,
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  /* <?php
       $query = mysql_query("select * from saved_positions") or die (mysql_error());
       while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
       { 
           $scl=$row['school_name'];
           $city=$row['city'];
           $lon2=urlencode($row['longitude_s']);
           $lat2=urlencode($row['latitude_s']);
   ?> */

  // New York, NY, USA (40.7127837, -74.00594130000002)
  // Newark, NJ, USA (40.735657, -74.1723667)

  var lat = 40.7127837;
  var lon = -74.0059413;
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: lat,
    lng: lon
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: myLatLng,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
  });
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

  var lat = 40.735657;
  var lon = -74.1723667;
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: lat,
    lng: lon
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: myLatLng,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
  });
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());


  // <?php
  //    }
  // ?>
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <input id="address" type="textbox" placeholder="type your address here" value="Jersey City, NJ">
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Click for location">
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```